# Conditionally render Nav in React Native App

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I have the following inside of App.js:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import NoNavScreen from "somewhere";
import NavScreen1 from "somewhere"
import NavScreen2 from "somewhere";
import MyNav from "somewhere";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => { 

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="nonav" component={NoNavScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="nav1" component={NavScreen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="nav1" component={NavScreen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

      <MyNav /> // I want to conditionally render this
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I want to conditionally render `MyNav` so that it is hidden on the `NoNavScreen`. I tried to simply place the component inside of `NavScreen1` and `NavScreen2`, but this causes a rerender on screen change and the nav state resets. Is there a way to conditionally render `MyNav` as shown above? If not, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/), *The easiest way to achieve this is to nest the tab navigator inside the first screen of the stack instead of nesting stack inside tab navigator*.

Using your naming approach would look like this:

```js
function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="NavScreen1" component={NavScreen1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="NavScreen2" component={NavScreen2} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="NoNavScreen" component={NoNavScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks that works! It took a while to restyle what I had but it's a better solution moving forward